# write form data to xls file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I just wanted to know if this is possible and if so, can i get a starting point.

Right now, I am looking to create an html form, and POST the data to an excel spreadsheet. I will be using PHP to POST the form data. The form will be set up as 2 tables. The 2 tables will be labeled as a Shortage table, and the other as an Overage table. I have a drop down menu with the names of people. what i am trying to accomplish is have the data write to an excel spreadsheet and separate the values from the shortage table and the values from the overage table. For example, if the shortage table contains 4 entries, and the overage contains 2 entries, in the excel spreadsheet i would like for cell A1 to say overage, row 2 will contain the column headers (i.e. date, description, size, etc...), and then have row 8 start off Overage, row 9 will have the headers, and row 10 on will contain the values inputted. Granted this will not always be the case, just an example.

My major goal is to have it set up this way. Each person will have a worksheet created specifically for them. This form will be used on a daily basis, so the filename will have the date on there. So each day the form will opened, and once the submit button has been pressed, i would like to have a worksheet created for that person containing the data from the 2 tables. For example, Bill Smith is the first entry today. the information from the 2 tables has been entered in, I select the submit button. Within the directory, there is an excel file labeled as, data03/29/16.xls. Within that excel workbook, a worksheet will contain the label/tab Bill Smith.

Is this at all possible, or would it be easier and efficient to write the form data to a CSV file?

Edit:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
<title> Drive Check In </title>

<script type = "text/javascript">

function reset()
{
  var driver = document.getElementById("drivers");
  var date = docuemt.getElementById("dates");
  var custnum = document.getElementById("customernum");
  var invnum = document.getElementById("invoicenum");
  var proddesc = document.getElementById("proddes");
  var sz = document.getElementById("size");
  var cs = document.getElementById("cs");
  var btls = document.getElementById("btls");
  var chkint = document.getElementById("chkitls");

  driver.value.reset();
  date.value.reset();
  custnum.value.reset();

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action = '' method = "post">
<table id = "shortages" >
<h1> Shortages </h1>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th> Driver </th>
  <th> Date </th> 
  <th> Customer# </th>
  <th> Invoice# </th>
  <th> Product Description </th>
  <th> Size </th>
  <th> CS </th>
  <th> Btls </th>
  <th> CHK Itls </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
  <td>
  <select id = "drivers" name = 'drivers'>
    <option value = " "> </option>
    <option value = "Driver1"> Driver1 </option>
    <option value = "Driver2"> Driver2 </option>
    <option value = "Driver3"> Driver3 </option>

  </select></td>

  <td> <input type = "text" id = "dates"size = "10" name = "dates"> </input> </td>
  <td> <input type = "number" min = "1" max = "99999999" id = "customernum" name = "customernum"> </input> </td>
  <td> <input type = "number" min = "1" max = "99999999" id = "invoicenum" name = "invoicenum"> </input> </td>
  <td> <input type = "text" id = "proddes" name = "proddes"> </input> </td>
  <td> <input type = "number" id = "size" name = "size"> </input> </td>
  <td> <input type = "number" id = "cs" name = "cs"> </input> </td>
  <td> <input type = "number" id = "btls" name = "btls"> </input> </td>
  <td> <input type = "text" id = "chkitls" name = "chkitls"> </input> </td>
</tr>

</table>

<input type = "submit" value = "submit" name = "mydrivers>

<?php

function myfputcsv($handle, $array, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $eol = "\n") {
    $return = fputcsv($handle, $array, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    if($return !== FALSE && "\n" != $eol && 0 === fseek($handle, -1, SEEK_CUR)) {
        fwrite($handle, $eol);
    }
    return $return;
}

if(isset($_POST['mydrivers']))  {  
$header=array();
$data=array();
 foreach (array_slice($_POST,0,count($_POST)-1) as $key => $value) {    
     //$header[]=$key;
     $data[]=$value;
 }  
$fp = fopen('driver.csv', 'a+');
    //fputcsv($fp, $header);
    myfputcsv($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}

?>
</form>

</html>
```

This is the php file that I have so far. I was using this without implementing your suggestions, but I will implement them.

This is my main output goal. After the cvs file is opened and formatted, this is the main goal.

[Main output goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbntT.png)

Edit 2:
After implementing your code, this is the output I am receiving. [Output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGmuO.png)

Comment: *Anything* is possible.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you. I  figure anything is possible, but I am unfamiliar with the ways of getting this accomplished

Comment: If that is the case you shouldn't have asked about the possibility of doing something, you should have asked how. But even at that the question would have been [too broad for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Sorry, i didn't want to ask how because i know with forums users will say to post code, and since i am just inquiring, i don't have any code produced at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is learn [PHPEXCEL](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). The second and quicker way is to use [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) and print your expected output in a normal html table:

```
<?php

$col1row = $_POST['col1row1'];//Getting data from form

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="16.xls"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
/*Saving purpose
**$output= @fopen('filename', 'w'); //error turn off
**$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
 */
//HTML table will go here
   $table = '<table><tr>';
   $table .= '<th>Column 1</th>';
   $table .= '<th>Column 2</th>';
   $table .= '</tr>';
   $table .= '<tr>';
   $table .= '<td>'.$col1row1.'</td>';
   $table .= '<td>'.$col2row1.'</td>';
   $table .= '</tr>';
   $table .= '<tr>';
   $table .= '<td>'.$col1row2.'</td>';
   $table .= '<td>'.$col2row2.'</td>';
   $table .= '</tr>';
   $table .= '</table>';
   echo $table;
?>
```

Save this code as excelout.php and run it. You will get your table in excel. Hope this may help for starting.

The CSV updated and working version:

```
function myfputcsv($handle, $array, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $eol = "\n") {
    $return = fputcsv($handle, $array, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    if($return !== FALSE && "\n" != $eol && 0 === fseek($handle, -1, SEEK_CUR)) {
        fwrite($handle, $eol);
    }
    return $return;
}
if(isset($_POST['mydrivers']))  {  
$header=array();
$data=array();
 foreach (array_slice($_POST,0,count($_POST)-1) as $key => $value) {    
     //$header[]=$key;
     $data[]=$value;
 }  
$fp = fopen('driver.csv', 'a+');
    //fputcsv($fp, $header);
    myfputcsv($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
```

I don't change much thing in your form except the following:

```
<form action = 'driver.php' target = 'driver.php' method = "post">
```

to

```
<form action=""  method ="post">
```

and

```
<input type = "submit" value = "submit" onsubmit = "this.reset()">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value ="submit" name="mydrivers">
```

You can check if $_POST if empty or not using array_filter():

```
$valid= array_filter($_POST);

if (!empty($valid)) {
   //all fields are furnished and can be saved.
}
```

[Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6xnk-rcww)

Comment: From the looks of the second header(), as soon as you hit submit, it will automatically download the file correct? If so, i would have to take that part out. Mainly because I will be entering in inputs at different times during the day. What I will do is save it to a specific location. I guess i will have to use the append attribute as well since i will be writing the data multiple times

Comment: Thank you very much for the start. I haven't had time to work on this, but I will play around with it. But i do have another question, where you are declaring `$row = getRow($result); ` what do you mean get data from database? I don't have a DB created and won't be working with a DB. The data would just be written straight to excel, or to a csv and then converted correctly in excel.

Comment: Ok...then you can create your own custom function getRow() to catch your data or you can loop your data like I did in my answer.

Comment: Show me the screen of your expected output. If my answer helps you, you can click the tick icon above.

Comment: I edit my post with code. I am working on implementing the code that you provided. But this is just a rough start of where I am, and i also provided an image with my main goal

Comment: I've updated my answer. please check it. I have tested in phpfiddle, it works. Hope this may help you. Look like you are using csv as database.

Comment: I edited my code to reflect what you have tested, and i am seeing php code being display starting with `$value` in the foreach statement until the end of the php. I have been looking for about an hr seeing if there is something missing to be outputting the php code on the form.

Comment: @bobdon, you are asking for the possibility of something. I gave you the possibility and now you keep asking for another question. If my code works, it's fine. Data validation is another thing. If you get any error in my code, please tell me. And if my answer helps you, please click the tick icon above.

Comment: Yes, I understand and I really appreciate your help with this. I will attach a screenshot of what I mean. It's not really an error, it's more of i'm not sure why this is happening. I loaded the code in phpfiddle, but the outcome is different. I will show you what I mean

Comment: @bobdon, Put all the php code at the top of your html code. You put the php code inside your form. That's wrong.

Comment: OK, sorry I did not know that. Thanks. Just to let you know, I had to create a separate PHP file and had the form action point to that php page. After doing that, your answer worked. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out with this. I will be working more on this to get the code to where I want it to be.